# Knowing which ListView has the focus on a form

Tags: c#, winforms

C# WinForms:

In some application like this:

[image]

I want to write a code for "Select All"  button. 
If I go and check which listview's "SelectedIndex" or "selected Item" property is greater than zero, then it won't work because what if user just has clicked inside the white area of them?

And also form.ActiveControl won't work either because when we click on "SelectAll" button, it is too late! ActiveControl is that SelectAll button.

maybe I could create a class level variable to remember which control has been clicked,etc..but I think there should be a better way....But what?!

Thanks

Comment: You want the select all button to select all items in the list that the user last clicked on?

Answer (score 2):

You could assign the 'GotFocus' event to a method like so, and record the 'last focused' control this way. Then in your SelectAll_CLick handler, if the listview is assigned, selectall, else - don't!

```
private ListView mLastSelectedListView;

private void ListViews_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)'
{
    ListView lv = sender as ListView;
    if (null == lv) return;
    mLastSelectedListView = lv;
}

private void SelectAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (null == mLastSelectedListView) return;
    mLastSelectedListView.SelectAll();
}
```

Here's a quick 'SelectAll' extension method to support the above;

```
public static class ListViewExtensions
{
    public static void SelectAll(this ListView lv)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem item in lv.Items)
            item.Selected = true;

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you think "Click" event is better or "GotFocus"?

Comment: I would go with GotFocus, because the user could select a List by tabbing to it.

Comment: yeah, good call. 
Hmm..ListView doesn't have a SelectAll() method, also tried ListView.Items.SelectAll()...

Comment: oh well, we can use a foreach to select them all...weired that it doesn't have such a method tho.

Comment: I wrote that code sample against Windows.Controls.ListView (WPF), which *does* have a SelectAll. Windows.Forms.ListView does not. Sorry about that! But as you say, you can write a simple method to do so.

Comment: Sample extension method for 'SelectAll' added.